# lock fixed header regardless of scrollbar to stop it moving

Tags: css

I have a site where the top header is fixed 100% width, and within that DIV I have another div 980px wide, centered.

When I load a which creates a browser scrollbar (due to page being long), the page loads and header loads but then jumps to the left, to accomodate the scrollbar.

I know I can add `overflow-y:scroll;` to the stylesheet to make a scrollbar always be there, but, that's no good as i use jquery fancybox v.2 which, if you do this on a long fancybox pop up, gives you two scrollbars. Fail.

So, is there a way to lock the middle section of the header as if a scrollbar is there but without there actually being one there? And it be in the same position regardless of whether scrollbar present or not.

This is CSS I'm using right now:

```
#topbar {
width:100%; 
height:51px;
margin:0;   
padding:0;  
position:fixed;
z-index:1000;
/*Making sure it sticks to left of window in IE7*/
top:0;
left:0;
float:left; 
background-color:#eeeeee;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.header { 
width:980px; 
margin:0 auto; 
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1001; 
left: 50%; 
margin-left: -490px; 
}
```

Its called e.g. `<div id="topbar"><div class="header">blah blah</div></div>`

Is there a solution?

Comment: I'd rather have the page scrollbar always visible and fix the whateverbox to work with that. Maybe temporarily set something to overflow: hidden; when a box is open?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/BwLdZ/